# Convert base64 data:url to image blob

Tags: jquery, ajax, base64, data-url, encodeuricomponent

I have an image cropper that takes in an image, immediately converts it to a blob

```
Blob {type: "image/jpeg", size: 40092, slice: function}size: 40092type: 
"image/jpeg"__proto__: Blob
```

before loading to the canvas. After cropping, the image is output in base64. I need to be able to convert the base64 image back to blob or image, so I can `POST` the image through AJAX to an API endpoint. I have the following that does all of this, but I can't figure out how to convert the rendered image back to a blob to `POST`. The current URL that is used to `POST`, looks like this in the console after hitting render, using `encodeURIComponent(dataUrl)`:

`http://url.com/rest/v1/utils/guid/encode?data%3Aimage%2Fjpeg%3Bbase64%2C%2F…hLGoZInTrWlH2qG7Az0okBRUnvTqXsaSoAKKKK0jsADrTqaOtOqgP%2F9k%3D&imageid=Test`

**This is the code used in the fiddle at the bottom**

```
    $(function () {
  var fileInput = document.getElementById("file")
    , renderButton = $("#renderButton")
    , imgly = new ImglyKit({
        container: "#container",
        ratio: 1 / 1
      });

  // As soon as the user selects a file...
  fileInput.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
    var file;

    var fileToBlob = event.target.files[0];
          var blob = new Blob([fileToBlob], {"type":fileToBlob.type});
          // do stuff with blob
          console.log(blob);
    // Find the selected file
    if(event.target.files) {
      file = event.target.files[0];
    } else {
      file = event.target.value;
    }

    // Use FileReader to turn the selected
    // file into a data url. ImglyKit needs
    // a data url or an image
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(file) {
      return function (e) {
        data = e.target.result;

        // Run ImglyKit with the selected file
        try {
          imgly.run(data);
        } catch (e) {
          if(e.name == "NoSupportError") {
            alert("Your browser does not support canvas.");
          } else if(e.name == "InvalidError") {
            alert("The given file is not an image");
          }
        }
      };
    })(file);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });

  // As soon as the user clicks the render button...
  // Listen for "Render final image" click
  renderButton.click(function (event) {
    var dataUrl;


    imgly.renderToDataURL("image/jpeg", { size: "1200" }, function (err, dataUrl) {
      // `dataUrl` now contains a resized rendered image with
      // a width of 300 pixels while keeping the ratio

       //Convert DataURL to Blob to send over Ajax
        function dataURItoBlob(dataUrl) {
        // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
        // doesn't handle URLEncoded DataURIs - see SO answer #6850276 for code that does this
        var byteString = atob(dataUrl.split(',')[1]);

        // separate out the mime component
        var mimeString = dataUrl.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

        // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
        var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
        var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
        for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
            ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        // write the ArrayBuffer to a blob, and you're done
        //var bb = new BlobBuilder();
        //bb.append(ab);
        //return bb.getBlob(mimeString);
        }


    var blob = dataURItoBlob(dataUrl);
    var fd = new FormData(document.forms[0]);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var saveImage = encodeURIComponent(dataUrl);
    //console.log(saveImage);


    fd.append("myFile", blob);
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://url.com/rest/v1/utils/guid/encode?' + saveImage + '&imageid=' + imageid.value, true);
    xhr.send(fd);

var image = $("<img><br>").attr({
        src: dataUrl
      });

      image.appendTo($(".result"))
      $button = $('<button class="btn btn-default remove">')
            .text('Remove')
            .on('click', function () {
                image.remove();
                $(this).remove();
                return false;
            });
        $button.appendTo($(".result"));
    });
  });
});
```

JSFIDDLE: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/Lgduvce1/10/)

Answer (score 0):

`dataURItoBlob` doesn't return anything, it should be returning a blob

```
return new Blob([ab], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
```

Also why are you putting the data url of the image in the url of the ajax post request?

Comment: What would be the best way to `POST` the data url image to the endpoint? Or should I somehow convert the data url back to an image, such as what I have in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/KAdN8/1/

Comment: That depends on what the endpoint API allows, but I'd go with FormData

Comment: What about using `toDataURL` to convert the resulting thumbnail image to jpeg? Such as here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL